# Supervised machine learning

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Module named `lab_utils_uni` is not installed by me

When I run the command `pip install lab_utils_uni`
I get the error "could not find the version that satisfies the requirements:
No matching distribution found" etc

I also imported `Numpy` and `Matplotlib`

I have tried several times to install and import `lab_utils_uni`. But there is an error when I am trying to install `lab_utils_uni` with the help of `pip` on `cmd`